# App crashes on launch when opened from test-flight using open button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, xcode11

When the application is installed on debug mode, no crashes are being observed. But, when the application is uploaded to test-flight(release build), the application is getting crash on launch.

The application works absolutely fine when opened from home screen. But, when open from test-flight interface(using open button). it crashes immediately.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001c7c66d94 _bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC<A>+ 2887060 (_:_:_:) + 392
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001c79d7d28 _forceBridgeFromObjectiveC<A>+ 204072 (_:_:) + 256
2   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001c7dfcc94 closure #2 in static Dictionary._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC+ 609428 (_:result:) + 224
3   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001c7ebbc38 thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Any, @in_guaranteed Any, @unowned UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> + 1391672 ()partial apply + 28
4   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001c7dfc890 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Any, @in_guaranteed Any, @unowned UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> + 608400 () + 112
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001992c3124 -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 248
6   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001c7dfbf98 static Dictionary._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC+ 606104 (_:result:) + 508
7   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001c7df0f28 static Dictionary._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC+ 560936 (_:) + 76
8   AppName                         0x0000000100960e80 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 413312 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c67fc80c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 416
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c67fdfdc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3432
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c68039fc -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1584
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6095e04 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c609e7e0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 168
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6095a6c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6096388 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1068
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c60945d0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 756
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c609428c -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 460
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6098fbc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 224
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6099e14 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 120
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6098e70 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 260
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c609de60 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6801f38 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 556
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c63e4650 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 376
24  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019bda1fd0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 456
25  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019bdac31c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 284
26  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019bdaba6c __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 72
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198ded888 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198df0e5c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 252
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019bddf18c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
30  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019bddee08 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 436
31  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019bddf404 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
32  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019936eb54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
33  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019936ead0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 92
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019936e38c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199369060 __CFRunLoopRun + 988
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199368964 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
37  GraphicsServices                0x000000019b5a9d8c GSEventRunModal + 108
38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c6805758 UIApplicationMain + 216
39  AppName                         0x00000001009007f8 main + 18424 (AppDelegate.swift:7)
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198e24fd8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198fefdc0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198fefdc0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198fefdc0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198f65c60 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019936e520 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001993691c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199368964 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x0000000199d49f3c -[NSRunLoop+ 32572 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x0000000199d49dc4 -[NSRunLoop+ 32196 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 100
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c68f136c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 140
7   Foundation                      0x0000000199d48b3c -[NSThread main] + 72
8   Foundation                      0x0000000199e7ee14 __NSThread__start__ + 988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198fe7908 _pthread_body + 132
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198fe7864 _pthread_start + 48
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198fefdcc thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000280d04604   x2: 0x0000000000000002   x3: 0x0000000000000018
    x4: 0x0000000000000043   x5: 0x0000000000000044   x6: 0x0000000100a32130   x7: 0x0000000000000007
    x8: 0x00000001d36b84e0   x9: 0x00000001c7ce1c50  x10: 0x000000002aa00000  x11: 0x000000000000014c
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x00000000000007fb  x14: 0x0000000000000008  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000198fb8488  x17: 0x00000001d1154f58  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016f501410
   x20: 0x0000000100a32130  x21: 0x00000001d0c7c5b8  x22: 0x00000001d38d82f0  x23: 0x000000016f501410
   x24: 0x00000001d0c7c5b8  x25: 0x00000001d1164e88  x26: 0x0000000282107700  x27: 0x00000001d3700000
   x28: 0x00000001d1166320   fp: 0x000000016f501400   lr: 0x00120a81c7c66c48
    sp: 0x000000016f5013d0   pc: 0x00000001c7c66d94 cpsr: 0x80000000
```

Comment: Looks like it’s crashing in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. What do you do there?

Comment: Try to use any crash reporter to zero in the crash. You can use Crashlytics. Its free and easy to install.

Comment: @KauthamKrishna I don't think this has anything to do with Crashlytics, i have already posted crash logs above.